# Create an equal numpy array of 1s and 0s from one with floating numbers and NaNs

Tags: arrays, numpy, nan

What is the most elegant way to create an equal sized array to "x1" (one that has both floating numbers and NaNs) into "x2" wherein:

```
floating number = 1
NaN = 0
```

Array is stock prices (1500 days x Dow 30 stocks).

Thanks!

Comment: Check `(~np.isnan(x1)).astype('int')`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Please don't answer in comments and don't answer without explanation.

Comment: @Yunnosch Sure. If you like you can add an answer..I'm happy to upvote you :)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma You misunderstood. I don't want you to answer unexplained in a comment, because that is not the idea of StackOverflow. You (not me) making an explained answer would be the ideal solution. Allowing me to harvest the reputation is kind and generous - but I can't.

Comment: Thanks @Yunnosch looks like Pablo already answered the question.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma You still miss my point. Please do not answer in comments. Keep in mind that giving solutions to peoples problem to them personally is just a side effect of StackOverflows goal to make a Q/A collection which is and stays useful for OTHER readers than just those posting the question. It is a business model thing... Also I personally try to minimise the length of the list of unanswered questions. It will stay long if people answer in comments and then nobody bothers to make a correct answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch I completely agree with you. I got the point :)

Answer (score 2):

I can think three ways, all use [`numpy.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html):

```
#setup
x = np.array([[1, 2, np.nan], [2.4, 0, 3], [np.nan, np.nan, 9]])
```

1. [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
np.where(np.isnan(x), 0, 1)
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

2. [`numpy.ndarray.astype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

```
(~np.isnan(x)).astype(int)
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

3. [`numpy.divide`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html)

```
np.divide(x, x, out = np.zeros_like(x), where = ~np.isnan(x))
array([[1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
#floats instead of integers here
```